RemoteTransportException: Fatal error at remote task manager
I'm working on moving our code from standalone processing to flink-cluster processing to make it more parallel. We are using a flink-version-1.15. The pipeline is running fine for a few minutes and then throws an exception. I read a couple of posts in StackOverflow and Google, but those are not related to the exception that I am getting
The exception that I am getting is:
 Caused by: org.apache.flink.runtime.io.network.netty.exception.RemoteTransportException: Fatal error at remote task manager 'AA.BB.CC.DD/AA.BB.CC.DD:6121'.

I explored the below posts that are throwing the same exception, but not Fatal error at remote task manager.
org.apache.flink.runtime.io.network.netty.exception.RemoteTransportException: Lost connection to task manager
How to assign memory for taskmanager properly?
Flink reduce shuffling overhead and memory consumption
Here is the full stack trace:
2024-10-24 20:21:53,263 WARN  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task  [] - MyWriterFunction (2/4)#0 (524db7c8a0ae3aedcd2a10891f12a263) switched from RUNNING to FAILED with failure cause: org.apache.flink.runtime.io.network.netty.exception.RemoteTransportException: Fatal error at remote task manager 'AA.BB.CC.DD/AA.BB.CC.DD:6121'.
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.io.network.netty.CreditBasedPartitionRequestClientHandler.decodeMsg(CreditBasedPartitionRequestClientHandler.java:288)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.io.network.netty.CreditBasedPartitionRequestClientHandler.channelRead(CreditBasedPartitionRequestClientHandler.java:181)
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.io.network.netty.NettyMessageClientDecoderDelegate.channelRead(NettyMessageClientDecoderDelegate.java:112)
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410)
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919)
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollStreamChannel$EpollStreamUnsafe.epollInReady(AbstractEpollStreamChannel.java:795)
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.processReady(EpollEventLoop.java:480)
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:378)
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:986)
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)


